# multi-class classification and imbalanced classes

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes

I have a data set of 145 images that I divide in to 96 images for training and 49 others for test. I have three classes which are imbalanced in Training set as well as in test set. In training set: class one:16 images; class two:56 images and class three: 24 images.
I used matlab to implement the multi-class (SVM) one against all, but i have a poor results in terms of Accurity mainly precission. I want to have a good classification so i can have a good measure of these images.
Is there any one who can help?

Comment: Unless you have (1) very simple classifier such as linear model and (2) very few and simple features for each image, I would say that you need at least an order of magnitude or more training data.

Comment: my learning data is a matrix whose size is (96x15). So I have 15 features for each image.

Comment: With 95 examples and 15 features each, there is perhaps a chance to build a classifier. Have you tried a linear classifier as your baseline?

Comment: I have already  tried the linear classifier but I have not the intended results as you can see. Class1 Class2 Class3
Accurity          0.7347
Precision                         0.6667  0.7500 0.7500
Recall                         0.6000 0.7778 0.7500
Specificity                 0.9231 0.6818 0.9189

Comment: I have already  tried the linear classifier but I have not the intended results as you can see. Class1 Class2 Class3
Accurity          0.7347
Precision                         0.6667  0.7500 0.7500
Recall                         0.6000 0.7778 0.7500
Specificity                 0.9231 0.6818 0.9189